# Input of character streams

Tags: c++, string, character

I am trying to input character streams, but I am getting weird results.

I am trying to count the number of `a's` and `b's` in each line.

The input format is as follows.

First line contains the number of test cases `(t)`.

Second line contains the number of lines `(n)`.

Next `n` lines contain `n` input streams of characters.

Here is the code snippet.

```
int t;
    cin>>t;

    while(t--)
    {
        int n;
        cin>>n;

        char ch;
        int arr[n][2]={};

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {



            while((ch != '\n'))
            {
                ch=getchar();

                if(ch == 'a')
                {
                    arr[i][0]++;
                }

                else if(ch == 'b')
                {
                    arr[i][1]++;
                }


            }


            cout<<arr[i][0]<<"\t"<<arr[i][1]<<endl;
        }
```

I give the following input :

```
1

3

ab

ba

aa
```

I get the following output :

```
0   0

1   1

1   1
```

But my expected output is :

```
1   1

1   1

2   0
```

> Looks like there is an extra `'\n'` coming for `i=0`, that is shifting the output by an `'i'`. How do I resolve this issue ?

Comment: That's an awful mix of C and C++. And what do you think happens to the newline you enter for `scanf`?. And C++ doesn't have variable-length arrays (you declare `arr` as a variable-length array), some compilers have it as an extension.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg : Doesn't work even with cin>>n . I will edit the question to avoid those answers.

Comment: Same problem as with `scanf`, what do you think happens with the newline in the input? Try step through the code line by line in a debugger, and see what `getchar` actually returns.

Comment: Oh and you have *undefined behavior*, because you use `ch` before it's initialized. Uninitialized non-static local variables have an *indeterminate* value, you need to initialize them before you use them.

Comment: I could make a working code using scanf("%s",&mystr) and ran the loop until I encountered '\0'.

Answer (score 0):

Your `char ch;` defines a char but doesn't initialize it, so its content is not predictable.

Then you use it in `while((ch != '\n'))` but `ch` is still not initialized at first step (when i=0), this is not a good practice.

You should try

```
for (...) {

  do {

    ch = getchar();

    <check content of 'ch'>

  } while (ch != '\n');

}
```

**or**

```
for (...) {

  ch = getchar();

  while (ch != '\n') {

    <check content of 'ch'>

    ch = getchar();

  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, (atleast on ideone.com ). Looks like there is a '\n' in the buffer that is interfering.

Comment: Try to `cout << (char) ch << endl;` after each call to `getchar` and see which unexpected character could print.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the end of line from the input stream when reading the number of lines, I suggest to use

```
scanf("%d\n",&n);
```

As mentioned by @A. Gille, you should also initialize ch before comparing it to anything.